# OrderByDescending on list of DateTime's not working?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

In a lambda expression, how do you order by a list of DateTime values, rather than an object?  For example, I want to get the most recent 3 pay dates on the following query:

```
 var hires = (from e in md.Employee
             where e.HireDate.Year == 2011
             select e.HireDate).Distinct();

 //at this point hires =
   6/3/2011
   5/15/2011
   6/1/2011
   7/1/2011
```

My assumption was that I could do `.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(3)`, but when I do so I don't get 7/1/2011 (just the first 3 above).  It's like the OrderByDescending is being ignored.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show a sample of your source data for us to simulate with?

Comment: What's the type of your data source?  I mocked up an Employees table with SQL Server using LINQ-To-SQL and it works just fine for me.

Comment: Looks like it might be an LLBL bug.  This particular code set was using LLBL's Linq implementation.  I mocked up something in a unit test w/ regular Linq and it worked fine as well.  I'll follow up with the LLBL folks.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you are putting the orderby & distinct in the right order?

Try:

```
var hires = (from e in md.Employee
    where e.HireDate.Year == 2011
    select e.HireDate).Distinct().OrderByDescending(e => e);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing.  No go.

Comment: @Jess - I'm thinking that `OrderByDescending` requires the entire enumerable to be evaluated first.

Comment: Looks like it might be an LLBL (an ORM) bug, so I'll accept this as the answer since it was the first.